# $1 of [...] has no declared type

Tags: yacc

I am unfamiliar with Yacc and trying to get an example I found [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Fie_prog_4lex_yacc.htm) to work. When I try to compile with `yacc -d calc.yacc`, I get the following errors.

> calc.yacc:42.17-18: $1 of `stat' has no declared type
>
> calc.yacc:96.22-23: $1 of `expr' has no declared type
>
> calc.yacc:105.17-18: $1 of `number' has no declared type
>
> calc.yacc:106.20-21: $1 of `number' has no declared type
>
> calc.yacc:110.29-30: $2 of `number' has no declared type

I tried googling and from what I can tell, the solution has to do with %type, but I'm not sure what to add.

The code is below:

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>

    int regs[26];
    int base;

    %}

    %start list

    %union { int a; }

    %type <a> expr number

    %token DIGIT LETTER

    %left '|'
    %left '&'
    %left '+' '-'
    %left '*' '/' '%'
    %left UMINUS  /*supplies precedence for unary minus */

    %%                   /* beginning of rules section */

    list:                       /*empty */
             |
            list stat '\n'
             |
            list error '\n'
             {
               yyerrok;
             }
             ;

    stat:    expr
             {
               printf("%d\n",$1);
             }
             |
             LETTER '=' expr
             {
               regs[$1] = $3;
             }

             ;

    expr:    '(' expr ')'
             {
               $$ = $2;
             }
             |
             expr '*' expr
             {

               $$ = $1 * $3;
             }
             |
             expr '/' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 / $3;
             }
             |
             expr '%' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 % $3;
             }
             |
             expr '+' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 + $3;
             }
             |
             expr '-' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 - $3;
             }
             |
             expr '&' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 & $3;
             }
             |
             expr '|' expr
             {
               $$ = $1 | $3;
             }
             |

            '-' expr %prec UMINUS
             {
               $$ = -$2;
             }
             |
             LETTER
             {
               $$ = regs[$1];
             }

             |
             number
             ;

    number:  DIGIT
             {
               $$ = $1;
               base = ($1==0) ? 8 : 10;
             }       |
             number DIGIT
             {
               $$ = base * $1 + $2;
             }
             ;

    %%
    main()
    {
     return(yyparse());
    }

    yyerror(s)
    char *s;
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",s);
    }

    yywrap()
    {
      return(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

$1, $2, and so on refer to the terms on the right-hand side of a grammar rule. For example in

```
stat:    expr
             {
               printf("%d\n",$1);
             }
             |
             LETTER '=' expr {
               regs[$1] = $3;
             }
```

LETTER '=' expr is one of the rules and in the following parentheses $1 refers to LETTER. `regs[$1] = $3;` will be made into a C statement but in order to do that, yacc needs to know what type $1 has. If you add

```
%type <a> LETTER
```

after the first %type declaration (or simply list `LETTER` after expr) the first error will be taken care of. Same goes for `DIGIT` and `base`. Note that there is nothing that refers to the value of stat (naturally) so there is no need for a %type declaration for stat. Thus in

```
calc.yacc:105.17-18: $1 of `number' has no declared type

calc.yacc:106.20-21: $1 of `number' has no declared type

calc.yacc:110.29-30: $2 of `number' has no declared type
```

the first line implies that `DIGIT` has an unknown type, the second line refers to the same problem with `number`; finally the last line reminds you to declare the type for `base`. Here is the yacc code it is referring to:

```
 number:  DIGIT
             {
               $$ = $1;
               base = ($1==0) ? 8 : 10;
             }       |
             number DIGIT
             {
               $$ = base * $1 + $2;
             }
             ;
```

Finally, without getting into too many details, the statement

```
regs[$1]=$3;
```

will be translated by yacc into something close to:

```
regs[YS[1].<type of LETTER>]=YS[3].<type of expr>;
```

where YS is a 'magic array' (actually yacc's stack); YS has the type of the declared %union. Thus you can see that to make this into legal C, yacc needs to know which member of the %union `<type of LETTER>` refers to. This is what the `%type` declaration is for.

Comment: Incidentally, all the errors would also go away if you removed the `%union` and `%type` directives.  The default type for the stack is `int`, and without a `%union` yacc assumes all tokens and nonterminals have the same type (`YYSTYPE` if I recall correctly, default `int` anyway).  Use `%union` and `%type` to set different types for different tokens/nonterminals.

Answer (score 1):

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int regs[26];
int base;
%}

%union { int a; }


%token DIGIT LETTER

%left '|'
%left '&'
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left UMINUS  /*supplies precedence for unary minus */


%type <a> stat expr number DIGIT LETTER

%%                   /* beginning of rules section */

list:    list stat  '\n'
         |
        list error '\n'
         {
           yyerrok;
         }
         | /*empty */
         ;
stat:    expr
         {
           printf("%d\n",$1);
         }
         |
         LETTER '=' expr
         {
           regs[$1] = $3;
         }

         ;

expr:    '(' expr ')'
         {
           $$ = $2;
         }
         |
         expr '*' expr
         {

           $$ = $1 * $3;
         }
         |
         expr '/' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 / $3;
         }
         |
         expr '%' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 % $3;
         }
         |
         expr '+' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 + $3;
         }
         |
         expr '-' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 - $3;
         }
         |
         expr '&' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 & $3;
         }
         |
         expr '|' expr
         {
           $$ = $1 | $3;
         }
         |

        '-' expr %prec UMINUS
         {
           $$ = -$2;
         }
         |
         LETTER
         {
           $$ = regs[$1];
         }

         |
         number
         ;

number:  DIGIT
         {
           $$ = $1;
           base = ($1==0) ? 8 : 10;
         }       
         |
         number DIGIT
         {
           $$ = base * $1 + $2;

         }
         ;

%%
main()
{
 return(yyparse());
}

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",s);
}

yywrap()
{
  return(1);
}
```

It is required to use **%type** directive to specify which members of union is used in which expressions.In order to use union member, a, we should use the aforementioned directive.
See More here [%type](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Type-Decl.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so. Please [edit] your answer to include such a description.