# yacc: (xxx) is untyped

Tags: c, yacc

here is my yacc file, when i use yacc -d xxx.y, it shows warning, i cant figure out why it make this mistake, i dont understand why it cant know what is $2, please guys, i need you help.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lex.yy.c"

extern int yylex();
extern FILE* yyin;
void yyerror(const char *s);

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
%}

%union {
    char* str;
}

%token TYPEDEF STRUCT CHAR SHORT INT FLOAT DOUBLE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON LBRACE RBRACE LBRACKET RBRACKET
%type <str>structDeclaration memDeclaration

%%

program:
    structDeclaration  { printf("public class %s {\n", $1);} 
    ;

structDeclaration:
    TYPEDEF STRUCT IDENTIFIER LBRACE memDeclaration RBRACE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON 
    {
        printf("}\n");)
    }
    ;

memDeclaration:
    INT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON { printf("    private int %s;\n", $2);}
    |CHAR IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON { printf("    private String %s;\n", $2);}
    |SHORT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON { printf("    private short %s;\n", $2);}
    |FLOAT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON { printf("    private float %s;\n", $2);}
    |DOUBLE IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON {printf("    private double %s;\n", $2);}
    ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unvalid %s\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!yyin) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    yyparse();

    fclose(yyin);
    return 0;
}
```

when i use yacc xxx.y,
it warns:  yacc: e - line 37 of "cstruct.y", $2 (IDENTIFIER) is untyped
i dont know which part is wrong

i dont know what to do yet.

Comment: [$1 of [...\] has no declared type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049349/1-of-has-no-declared-type)

Answer (score 1):

In several lines you refer to IDENTIFIER which is untyped. Here is one example:

```
INT IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON { printf("    private int %s;\n", $2);}
```

When you have fixed these errors, you will get more errors later, because you don't assign a `char *` to neither `structDeclaration` nor `memDeclaration`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a declaration

```
%token IDENTIFIER
```

which declares `IDENTIFIER` as a token with no type (there are other tokens declared on the same line, but this is the key part)

If you instead use

```
%token<str>  IDENTIFIER
```

it will declare IDENTIFIER as a token with `str` type -- it has an associated `char *` value accessable as `$`*n* in actions (*n* being the index of the token.)

Since you use `$2` referring to an `IDENTIFIER`, you need this later declaration.

In addition, you declare `type<str> structDeclaration`, which means that `structDeclaration` similarly has an associated `char *`.  That means that actions for that rule should set `$$` to specify the value.  If they don't you'll instead get the value associated with the first terminal on the rhs of the rule (if any), and an error if that value does not exist or has the wrong type.